# How to toggle between .h and .m in Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

Just installed Xcode 4 so far so good, except that Apple changed all the keyboard shortcuts! Anyone know how to toggle between .h and .m?

Comment: Just for any future readers.  The key is that in the Xcode menus, the words you're looking for are "Jump" and "Counterpart" (rather non-intuitive)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Apple changed all sorts of shortcuts, but to switch between header and implementation, the new shortcut is,

<kbd>⌃</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>

You can change it back to the previous <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> +  <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> in `Preferences` > `Key Bindings`.

Look for the **Jump to Next Counterpart** and **Jump to Previous Counterpart** commands.

If you are working on a big screen, you could use the Assistant layout's split view, and have the .h and .m files side by side.

Comment: The left and right arrow keys move back and forward through the history. Up and down keys only alternate between the header and implementation.

Answer (score 19):

[Hither be the Grand Unified Gigantic Sheet of Xcode 4 Keybindings.](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html)

```
Download it.
Preview it.
Print it.
Read it.
Know it.
Use it.
Be it.
```

Comment: i looked that over before asking the question.  the command is labeled "Jump to Next Counterpart" I didn't deduce that to mean what I was looking for.

Comment: Yup -- it was more of a "if there is a keybinding, it will be here" answer.

Comment: Fantastic I agree with this thought process!

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the 3 finger swipe up or down gesture on a trackpad.

Comment: Check in System Preferences / Trackpad in the "Three Fingers" section.  With "Swipe to Navigate" checked, it works.  With "Dragging" checked, the gesture selects text.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the swipe can still work in Lion.  I thought it was a goner.  As a side note, it looks like my default configuration now as the swipe setup as two fingers left and right, in case anyone else wants to continue the trackpad gestures, but doesn't want to muck around in the trackpad configuration.

Comment: Slight correction, the left right swipe actually looks like it moves between file history.  I just coincidentally opened the header and source files in sequence.

Comment: I have 3 finger swipe set for selecting. But using 4 finger swipes up/down works for me for switching between .h and .m files.

Answer (score 2):

The commands we're looking for are in the `Navigate` menu bar item.

`Jump to Next Counterpart`

and

`Jump to Previous Counterpart`

Once you have the menu item names, these can be assigned to any keyboard shortcut.