# Is there a way in Xcode to go to the last edit location?

Tags: xcode, command, shortcut

Is there a way in Xcode to go to the last edit location? I know the Command + Z combination, but when I go to another location to edit, Command + Z doesn't go to the last edit location. Instead it goes to the current location. Is there any way to go to the last edit location like  in Eclipse?

Also, when I do Command + left-click in a controller, I want to go to the controller's `.m` file, but it goes to the `.h` file instead. Is there any way go to the implementation file?

Or is there any way to create way a shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second answer, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334066/how-to-toggle-between-h-and-m-in-xcode-4).  You can toggle between the source and header using

```
Ctrl + Cmd + [up|down]
```

Comment: thank for you answer but when i watch a class in controller,i need command + leftclick to go to a class's header and then ctrl + cmd +[up|down] go to source,there are tow step,is there any way for one step go to source?

Comment: Usually I just click on the file name in the explorer project navigator.   Or right click and jump to the definition.  It would be great if there was just one click for it, though...

Comment: usually i use quick open to open file...i feel click file name is too slow